# Error: Shell Form does not validate

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a registration script using jQuery/ajax. The first part validates as the user fills, which works fine, but the script is supposed to throw an alert if they try and submit before their input is validated. It isn't working and I wasn't getting any console errors either. I posted the script in jsfiddle and got the following lengthy error:

> {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name':
>   u'initial-js_lib', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id':
>   u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field':
>   ,
>   'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name':
>   u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id':
>   u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field':
>   ,
>   'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}

Here is the code I am using. I included the working validate function, in case that is somehow interfering.

```
function checkForm() {
// Fetches and stores values
var name = document.getElementById("username1").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email1").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password1").value;
var age = document.getElementById("age1").value

// Checks for blanks
if (name == '' || email == '' || password == '' || age == '') {
    alert("You must fill in all fields!");
} else {
    // Notifying error fields
    var username1 = document.getElementById("username");
    var email1 = document.getElementById("email");
    var password1 = document.getElementById("password");
    var age1 = document.getElementById("age");

    if (username1.innerHTML == "Username must have at least 3 characters!"
     || username1.innerHTML == "Username cannot contain special characters!"
     || username1.innerHTML == "Username is already taken!"
     || email1.innerHTML == "Invalid email."
     || password1.innerHTML == "Password is too short!"
     || password1.innerHTML == "Password must contain at least one number."
     || password1.innerHTML == "Password must contain at least one letter."
     || age1.innerHTML == "You must be at least 13!") {
        alert("Please fill valid information!");
    } else {
        // Submits if all are valid
        document.getElementById("registerform").submit();
    }
}
}

// Ajax onblur event
function validate(field, query) {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // For IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // For IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Validating..";
    } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Error Occured! Reload or try again.";
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/lib/registerProcess.php?field=" + field + "&query=" + query, false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and my html form:

```
    <form id="registerform" name="registerform" method="post" action="#">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" tabindex="1" onblur="validate('username', this.value)"></td>
            <td><div id="username"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="email">Email</label></td>
            <td><input type="email" tabindex="2" onblur="validate('email', this.value)"></td>
            <td><div id="email"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" tabindex="3" onblur="validate('password', this.value)"></td>
            <td><div id="password"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="age">Age</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="age" tabindex="5" onblur="validate('age', this.value)"></td>
            <td><div id="age"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" name="submitReg" id="submitReg" value="Sign Up" onsubmit="checkForm(); return false;"></center></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

After doing some research, it is my understanding that the reason I'm getting this is because my form is attempting to reload the page on submit, which jQuery doesn't like. In my attempt to fix, I swapped my submit event from `onclick="checkForm()"` to `onsubmit="checkForm(); return false;"` but to no avail.

What can I do to prevent the post event from reloading the page? Or is my problem something different altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Try change this line `onsubmit="checkForm(); return false;"`
to
`document.getElementById("submitReg").addEventListener("click", checkForm);`
paste this in your js code